# Portfolio's Historical data import on R

Tags: r, csv, graph, dataset

I want to import my data set in R, I have used different methods but the final result is always the same: the first column intended to be the timeframe is not taken into consideration by R. This creates problem with the general analysis both analytical and graphical.

Here below an example of the data set (the final result I'd like to achieve):

```
Data         ISEGILA.LN   ISEOVRA.LN   IMKSFIP.LN
2010-04-05   247,32       201,21       240
2010-04-06   244,95       200,55       238,4
2010-04-07   243,41       200,55       237,2
2010-04-08   242,75       200,39       237
```

Here below the comma separated one to create the cvs file

```
Data;ISEGILA.LN;ISEOVRA.LN;IMKSFIP.LN
2010-04-05;247,32;201,21;240
2010-04-06;244,95;200,55;238,4
2010-04-07;243,41;200,55;237,2
2010-04-08;242,75;200,39;237
```

After using this code:

```
dataset <- read.csv2("Dataset.csv", header = TRUE)
```

I obtain this (with a column of numbers added):

```
    Data         ISEGILA.LN   ISEOVRA.LN   IMKSFIP.LN
1   2010-04-05   247,32       201,21       240
2   2010-04-06   244,95       200,55       238,4
3   2010-04-07   243,41       200,55       237,2
4   2010-04-08   242,75       200,39       237
```

And if I try to plot the dataset, the x-axis does not show the data column

```
library("quantmod")
library("yuima")    

ISEGILA.LN <- c(dataset[, 2])
ISEOVRA.LN <- c(dataset[, 3])
IMKSFIP.LN <- c(dataset[, 4])
dataprice <- zoo(cbind(ISEGILA.LN, ISEOVRA.LN, IMKSFIP.LN))
colnames(dataprice) <- c("ISEGILA.LN", "ISEOVRA.LN", "IMKSFIP.LN")
plot(dataprice, main = "Dataset Example")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering is that the read.table set of functions (including read.csv2) assumes that the first column of your document is part of the data set and should not be used as the index. R then assigns in row an index number from `1:nrow(data.frame)`

If you want to have your dates be the index for your data you can try `rownames(dataset) <- dataset$Data`. Another route to plot without having to re-index your data is to `plot(x=dataset$Data, y=dataset$variable, main = "Dataset Example")`

Comment: Both solutions are interesting, but: the `rownames` command seems to change nothing while the `plot` command does not work due to difference in axis length and/or the class of the date column.

Comment: Once you convert it to the zoo data series you can use the index function to transform your data and change the index. I think this is what you are trying to do: `index(dataprice) <- dataset$Data` This seems to get the plot that you are after if I understand you correctly. As for the plotting, you are correct that the above won't work, it should be `plot(x=dataset$Data, y=dataset$ISEGILA.LN, main = "Dataset Example")`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert it to a zoo object :

```
read.zoo("Dataset.csv", header = TRUE)
```

The vignette is here: 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-read.pdf

Comment: Thanks! It looks helpful, actually in the PDF it's missing my case. Do you have more hints for my issue?

Comment: In the case of the data shown in the question `z <- read.zoo("Dataset.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",")` would create a zoo object and `fortify.zoo(z)` would create a data frame.  (This assumes that comma is the decimal point.)